# Graphing with rolling mean data not smoothing properly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot

When trying to plot a rolling mean in pandas to smooth my data using the following code I get a strange appearing graph

```
data['mean_Kincaid'] = pd.rolling_mean(data.Kincaid,30, min_periods=1)
data['Year']= data['Date'].dt.year
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid')
```

Which yields the following graph: [image]

I would like the graph to be 'smoother' (my goal in using the rolling_mean function to begin with).

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Update: Image with suggested code[image]

Update 2: With the following code I was able to produce the following image -- any idea on how to fix the x-axis to just the year?

```
data['mean_Kincaid'] = data.Kincaid.rolling(75, min_periods=1).mean()
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid')
```

[image]

When I run it with the following code I get the error "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" Thanks!

Update 3:

```
data['mean_Kincaid'] = data.Kincaid.rolling(10000, 
min_periods=1).mean()
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid', legend=False, title="Kincaid 
scores over time")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is insufficient smoothing.

```
n = 8001
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Kincaid=np.sin(np.linspace(-4, 4, n)) + np.random.rand(n) * 2,
        Date=pd.date_range('2010-03-31', periods=n)
    ))

df['mean_Kincaid'] = df.Kincaid.rolling(30, min_periods=1).mean()

df.plot(x='Date', y=['Kincaid', 'mean_Kincaid'])
```

[image]

This is better

```
df['mean_Kincaid'] = df.Kincaid.rolling(360, min_periods=1).mean()

df.plot(x='Date', y=['Kincaid', 'mean_Kincaid'])
```

[image]

Notice the larger window parameter.

Comment: Thanks, however when I run the code I get this ugly looking thing (I added it at the bottom of my question as an update) -- is there a way for me to smooth it out to look more like yours? I've tried playing around with the window to no avail!

Comment: Maybe with a resample()

Comment: @GrahamStreich I don't know what your data looks like.  You may have extremely high frequency and rolling over 30 periods isn't enough.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to fix the axis labels? Please see the updates to my question -- I think we're getting close to having solved it!

Comment: Your `Date` column is no longer `datetime`.  Do this `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

Comment: ahh, but when I do that it gets wonky again...please see the update...I fiddled with the periods to no avail...thanks!

Comment: could it have to do with NaN values in the dataframe?

Comment: Convert your dates, then sort by them then rolling mean `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date); df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True); df['mean_Kincaid'] = df.Kincaid.rolling(75, min_periods=1).mean()`

Comment: I did, but since i don't have enough of a reputation it doesn't appear but is supposedly 'recorded' :p Thanks again!

Comment: Oh wait, I just got the privilege!